# how to combine table into array variable in PHP?

Tags: php

SELECT `mgr_id`, `mgr_name`, `branch`,  FROM `new_manager`.
I want combine above three columns it have 27 fields. 
I want combine these 27 fields into single array variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT mgr_id, mgr_name, branch FROM new_manager WHERE 1');
$data = array();
while($result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[]['mgr_id'] = $result_row['mgr_id'];
    $data[]['mgr_name'] = $result_row['mgr_name'];
    $data[]['branch'] = $result_row['branch'];
}
print_r($data);
?>
```